# REST API security: HMAC/key hashing vs JWT

Tags: security, rest, authentication, keys, hmac

I just [read this article](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) that is a few years old but describes a clever way of securing your REST APIs. Essentially:

- Each client has a unique public/private key pair
- Only the client and the server know the private key; it is never sent over the wire
- With each request, the client takes several inputs (the entire request itself, the current timestamp, and the private key) and runs them through an HMAC function to produce a hash of the request
- The client then sends the normal request (which contains the public key) and the hash to the server
- The server looks up the client's private key (based on the provided public key) and does some timestamp check (that admittedly I don't understand) that verifies the request is not a victim of a [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)
- If all is well, then the server uses the private key and the same HMAC function to generate its own hash of the request
- The server then compares both hashes (the one sent by the client as well as the one it generated); if they match, the request is authenticated and allowed to proceed

I then stumbled across [JWT](http://jwt.io), which sounds very similar. However the first article does not mention JWT at all, and so I am wondering if JWT is different than the above auth solution, and if so, how.

Comment: Lol... I just wanted to ask the same exact question and came across yours. One of the first things I found about stateless authentication was from the AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/HMACAuth.html , and implemented something like this http://massimilianosciacco.com/implementing-hmac-authentication-rest-api-spring-security . Then I found JWS/JWT and it is somehow similar. But as far as I understand JWT is a standard and the other solutions described above are some custom implementations (not standardized). Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one worrying about these kinds of details! JWT certainly *feels* similar, and the bonus is that it's standardized. I'm just wondering how it fairs (security-wise) with this custom HMAC solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's get this started with a very basic answer.

JWT (as used in the context of OAuth and OpenID) does not require shared secrets between client and API. There are 3 components and pairs of 2 share a secret each: client <-> identification server, identification server <-> API.

This moves most complexity from the API to the identification server, the API just has to check that the token was issued by the identification server and was not tempered with. To verify that the API checks that the JWT-signature is valid with the known single shared secret between identification server and API. That's it!

How the identification server validates the user identity can vary widely (in many cases it's the old username+password pair over a TLS-connection), but is of no effect on your API.

Privacy and security of the message and the token itself when using JWT are handled by TLS, JWT is ignorant of such issues.

Comment: I found this answer to be confusing. It handwaves details like, "JWT (as used in the context of OAuth and OpenID)" Might be worth explaining why that is instead of assuming the readers implicitly understand that.

Answer (score 1):

### disclaimer

this is based on a lots of reading and the implementation of both patterns in production systems; but, as usual with answers on the internet, this should be considered as a starting point and not a definitive conclusion

### tl:dr

- `jwt` - great for user auth (scales well; low-cost, low-latency, low-dependency)

  - facebook
  - oauth
  - etc
- `hmac+key` - great for sdk auth (safer for longer living keys since the `request-signature` is single use)

  - aws
  - visa
  - etc

### pros and cons

**jwt's**

- summary

  - the `client-private-key` is used as the `request-signature` and so is sent on every request, increasing vulnerability

    - however, in consumer applications, the `client-private-key` is only as safe as the device it is stored on anyway, so using it as the `request-signature` is likely not the biggest risk
  - the `request-signature` does not vary per request, so in case of a leak of the `request-signature`, the attacker can make any request they want

    - however, in consumer applications, the access granted is typically scoped to only that user, so the damage they can do is limited in scope
- pros:

  - summary

    - distributed + stateless
  - details

    - the `request-signature`, the jwt, can be authenticated publicly, by anyone

      - [distributed] no api calls to issuer-server required, `client-public-key` is published at wellknown url, cacheable, static
      - [stateless] no state to manage, access, or upkeep for authenticating requests
    - the `request-signature`, the jwt, identifies the requester and scope

      - [distributed] no api calls to issuer-server required, client identity is embedded and extractable from the `request-signature`
      - [stateless] no state to manage, access, or upkeep for identifying the requester
  - effect

    - no centralized state gatekeeper/bottleneck
    - no added latency due to queries against some database
    - no added cost for provisioning databases
    - no scaling issues as the number of tokens increases (expiration x users = gets large fast)
- cons:

  - summary

    - the `client-private-key` === the `request-signature` === the jwt
  - details

    - the `client-private-key` (the jwt) is transmitted over the wire (could be leaked through usage)
    - the `request-signature` (the jwt) does not vary per message (if leaked, can be used to make any request)
    - the `client-private-key` (the jwt) is stored in plaintext by the client (can be leaked from storage device)

**hmac+keys's**

- summary

  - the issuer must keep a database of the `client-keypairs` they issued and access it's data to authenticate each `request-signature`, increasing latency and cost
  - however, the `request-signature` is single use when implemented w/ nonce, so there is no risk in it being stolen through usage, making it safer to have longer living `client-keypairs` for backend applications
- pros

  - summary

    - eliminates vulnerabilities present in jwt based auth, making it safer to use when managing more than the data of one user
  - details

    - the `client-private-key` is never sent over the wire, eliminating the possibility of it being leaked through usage
    - the `request-signature` changes for each request (and can be made immune to replays), eliminating any risk from `request-signature`s being leaked
  - effect

    - keeps the `client-private-key` more secure over time
- cons

  - summary

    - centralized + stateful
  - details

    - you have to save the `client-public-key` and the `client-private-key-hash` in a database, along with scope and identity
    - you have to lookup the `client-private-key-hash` for each authentication request, along with scope and identity
    - the `client-private-key` is stored in plaintext by the client (can be leaked from storage device)

## comparison in flow

here's a breakdown in the flow of `keypairs` and `signatures` used in both patterns.

you'll see a  wherever there is a systematic vulnerability

for **jwt**:

- issuer creates `issuer-keypair` (openssl keypair)

  - publishes `issuer-public-key` publicly at the [openapi discovery flow url](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/id/draft-ietf-oauth-discovery-08.html)
  - securely retains `issuer-private-key` to sign jwts with
- issuer creates `client-keypair` (a jwt token)

  - effectively, `client-public-key` = `issuer-public-key`, which is already publicly published by issuer
  - the `client-private-key` is the jwt, sent to client, forgotten by issuer
- client retains `client-keypair`

  - `client-public-key` reference is embedded in `client-private-key` (as jwt.issuer)
  - `client-private-key` retained as plaintext  (vuln. because this depends on client secure storage implementation)
- client signs requests and sends request with signature to backend

  - `request-signature` = `client-private-key`

    - (vuln. because the secret, the jwt, is sent in each request; increases chance of leak)
    - (vuln. because the request-signature does not depend on the request; if leaked, can be used to make any request)
- backend authenticates request against the signature

  - looks up `client-public-key` data

    - from the well-known url that the `issuer-public-key` is published at (since effectively `issuer-public-key` = `client-public-key`)
  - confirms `request-signature` is authentic against `client-public-key`

    - openssl signature check
  - looks up `identity` from `request-signature`
  - confirms `request` is authorized against `identity`

for **hmac+key**:

- issuer creates `client-keypair` for client

  - `client-public-key` -> sent to client, retained in database as plaintext by issuer
  - `client-private-key` -> sent to client, hashed to compare against in database by issuer
- client retains `client-keypair`

  - `client-public-key` retained as plaintext
  - `client-private-key` retained as plaintext  (vuln. because this depends on client secure storage implementation)
- client signs requests and sends requests with signature to backend

  - `request-signature` = `hash(hash(client-private-key), request)`
- backend asks issuer to authenticate request against the signature

  - looks up `client-public-key` data

    - from the database that the plaintext `client-public-key` and hashed `client-private-key-hash` are persisted to
  - confirms `request-signature` is authentic against `client-public-key` data

    - `request-signature === hash(client-private-key-hash, request)`
  - looks up `identity` from `client-public-key` data
  - confirms `request` is authorized against `identity`